# Android SQLite database gets corrupted

Tags: android, sqlite

This link describes my problem exactly: http://old.nabble.com/Android-database-corruption-td28044218.html#a28044218

There are about 300 people using my Android App right now and every once and while I get a crash report to the server with this stack trace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.native_fill_window(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:75)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:295)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:276)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:171)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:248)
```

The result is the app crashing and all the data in the DB being lost.

One thing to note is that every time I read or write to the database I get a new SQLiteDatabase and close it as soon as I'm done.  I did this in an attempt to prevent these kind of corruption errors.

I also tried synchronizing all DB reads and writes using a single static object and that didn't seem to help.

Is it possible this is just a SQLite bug?

I found a similar bug with the built-in email app here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5610.

Here is my code:

```
public class KeyValueTableAdapter extends BaseTableAdapter {

    private String tableName;
    private String keyColumnName;
    private String valueColumnName;

    public KeyValueTableAdapter(Context context, String tableName, String keyColumnName, String valueColumnName) {
        super(context);
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.keyColumnName = keyColumnName;
        this.valueColumnName = valueColumnName;
    }

    protected String getStringValue(int key) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        String value;

        try {
            db = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = db.query(true, tableName, new String[] { valueColumnName }, keyColumnName + "=" + key, null, null, null, null, null);

            if ((cursor.getCount() == 0) || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                value = null;
            } else {
                value = cursor.getString(0);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
            if (db != null) db.close();
            dbOpenHelper.close();
        }

        return value;
    }
}


public abstract class BaseTableAdapter {

    protected DbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public BaseTableAdapter(Context context) {
        this.dbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(context, DatabaseSettings.DATABASE_NAME, null, DatabaseSettings.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use triggers on your database?

Comment: Nope, this particular table is just a "key/value table".  Two columns: one primary key (integer) and another non-null (text).  Do you think using text might be the problem? I'm a little unfamiliar with SQLite's typing.

Comment: SQLite is typeless, that doesn't count. You can push text in a date field :)

Comment: That's what I figured, plus it's failing at cursor.moveToFirst(), not getString or getInt or whatever.

Comment: I had a corrupt db problem, when I was issuing some drop/create table/views/triggers while I was in a transaction. As it turns out SQLite transaction can hold only table specific queries, not schema related.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> "the DB holds session information so
>   it's not very feasible to do a backup.
>   The data changes by the minute"

You should try using SharedPreferences: it stores key-value pairs (in the background, it uses a file).
Storing values:

```
SharedPreferences sp=MyActivity.getSharedPreferences("Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("key", value);
editor.putBoolean("another", true);
editor.commit();
```

Retrieving data:

```
sp.getString("key", "Not found"); 
// "Not found" is the default value
// if sp does not contain the specified key
sp.getBoolean("another", false); 
// false is the default value
// if sp does not contain the specified key
```

See [getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences) and [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for a more detailed description.

Comment: The problem is related to the database and thus a solution to use the shared prefs is not a solution.

Comment: The problem is related to the database and thus not using a database can be a solution, especially when based on Brandon's comments, it's not even the best way to store his data (small, frequently changing key-value pairs).

Comment: Point here is to solve the problem and not work around it. Usually workarounds have a way of getting back at you.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely the database process(es) is getting killed during an I/O. For example by a task killer, or if you're allowing db write operations to continue during a time when the app should shutdown or sleep...

See if you can reproduce the issue by putting your app in a DB write loop and using a task killer on it.

Scenario: 32 bytes being written to the database, the writer task gets killed after only writing 10, result: database left in inconsistent and possibly corrupt state.

Also see:
[Android process killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720164/android-process-killer)

EDIT: opening and closing the DB for each read/write? stop that! :)

Comment: Thanks, I actually came back here to report exactly that.  I can re-create it with a task killer app.  According to this article it is a bug in SQL lite: http://www.pubbs.net/201003/sqlite/60719-sqlite-android-database-corruption.html

Comment: Also, the reason I'm trying to open and close the DB for each write is to avoid this problem.  Wouldn't that solve the problem?  The user would have to get really lucky and kill it in between open and close.

Comment: Depending on how often you're writing to the DB, It could either help you or hurt you. the open/close may add enough overhead that frequent writes plus open/close leaves a bigger window for problems to occur. On the other hand, if you are writing infrequently, the open/close may flush the bytes to "disk" for you so they're not hanging out in memory at risk of being lost. I would probably add a big ugly message that displays if the user corrupts the DB. "HEY IDIOT YOU ARE RUINING YOUR PHONE BY KILLING TASKS!" :)

Comment: It's a bug in SQLite (per your first comment to this answer), can I have the bounty now :p

Comment: Even if the database write is aborted at random, it should not corrupt - that's kind of the point.  So, either there's an sqlite bug in the commit/recovery logic, or there's an OS bug with regards to fsync (or equivalent) - and opening and closing the DB for each read write shouldn't be problematic, although it may reduce performance (then again, it might not, particularly if you have a bunch of writes)

Comment: He already stated that he was able to reproduce the problem by using the task killer. This question has been answered 10 times over.

Comment: It also happens to my users who don't user task killers though.  I definitely appreciate your answer, but I'm also trying to figure out a workaround in the case when a task killer isn't used.  I'm close to giving up on SQLite and rolling my own persistence layer using files or maybe shared preferences.

Comment: @Brandon, I understand. I'm noticing a bit of churn on the issue so it may be helpful to redirect our attention to specific cases, and work toward a set of steps which lead to the issue. At present, we're really just guessing.

Comment: By the way, Is there any way to make the code more "tread-kill" safe?

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple instances of `SQLiteDatabase` could be causing your problem if you have two instances updating the same database file at the same time.

Comment: I do just that in one of my apps without any problems... sqlite locks the database file during write operations so they are actually atomic (and thus thread safe) at a file system level.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a backup db process each day, and if the DB gets corrupted you just replace the database with a backup. You can use simple file copy paste methods to maintain a backup each day.

Comment: Thanks, but the DB holds session information so it's not very feasible to do a backup.  The data changes by the minute and is crucial for the app to run.

Comment: It's still a backup way to go if you don't want to lose everything. I know this is the last thing on earth to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment -yet- on Brad's post.

I have to agree with the extra overhead.

I have a HTC Magic as my daily phone, and ram is always an issue.

Android phones are at very different ends of the $$$

Some are super cheap and some are super expensive, this basically comes down to ram, and cpu.

People who run task killers do ruin their android phones.

As a developer you should suggest people not to use them, or just deny support to people who use task killers, since android doesn't need these "improvements" (ask steve (cyanogen))

Also the `new` statement in android is very expensive.

You want to limit the amount of `new` calls when programming for android.

Programming for android is all about reuse of the precious memory. (HTC Magics/Dreams only have 96MB available to applications, and most of it is already in use)

As for your SQLiteDB...the API says that your SQLiteDB is private to your application.

I don't see why you need to open and close a NEW connection to it each time you want to read or write to it.

I would rather keep the connection open until the user looses focus from it.

However, if you are writing a content provider, that is a different story.

Comment: It's still happening about 5 times a day so I'm pretty certain that it isn't just people using task killers.  I have just found that I can sometimes cause the same exception using a task killer..  As for opening and closing the DB connection every time -- I was just making the point that I'm willing to add the extra overhead as long as the DB doesn't get corrupted (though I'm not sure if opening/closing will really solve the problem, I'm just trying everything)

Comment: It could be an SQLite bug in android, but android devices normally have very limited resources. So creating as little overhead as possible will improve the speed and stability of any android application. It seems like you are creating unnecessary garbage per query. The OS's lowMemoryKiller can probably create the same problems as a task killer. As your application isn't as important as the other system services.