# Block Specific Android Applications to connect to Internet

Tags: android

I need to create an application that will block applications to connect to internet when a certain threshold has reached. I just like to ask if this app is possible even the user of the app will not root his android phone? I have check droidwall but that app requires rooting the phone.

Comment: You could try messing around with the APN settings just like [apndroid](https://code.google.com/p/apndroid/) does. This will prevent all apps from accessing mobile networks.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=android+firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible <sup>(*)</sup> but on a rooted phone. Each application is independant of each other and an application A cannot override a permission granted to an application B.

And this is logical as if the user have installed that Application B that was requiring the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission, this is not to see an Application A to decide anything else.

<sup>(*) At least with Android <= 9. I don't know the newer versions so well but I would be really surprised they bring any change to that principle.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I just simply close an application using its PID? Do android allow me to do that? I check killProcess(pid) but it cannot all apps.

Comment: This should be feasible as this is the way the famous app AdvancedAppKiller works, but this is strongly discouraged. There is an interesting topic about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720164/android-process-killer and some searches on Google show other resources about that.

Comment: i'm quite confused with killProcess and killBackgroundProcesses, can I use one of these to close the application. THANKS AGAIN!