# Terminating the browser programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to close/terminate the browser programmatically. But I did not find any method in the default browser Class. Does anyone know how to?

Comment: Browser extends webview. What you wants to do you wants to close browser application?

Comment: I'm trying to open and close the default browser with the help of my code(using an activity class)

Comment: You can call intent and let the user choose on which browser he wants to surf.

Answer (score 3):

Killing prcesses in android is bad idea and it is never encouraged. but if still you want to continue with this you could do something like this.

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = servMng.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if(list != null){
     for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
      if("com.android.browser".matches(list.get(i).processName)){
       int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName("com.android.browser");
             android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
      }
     }
    }
```

but also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2720404/443387).

A nice answer, this will give you detailed description of why this method of killing processes is discouraged.

Comment: Note that this will not work, as is clearly indicated by [the documentation for `killProcess()`](http://goo.gl/vP7kA). This would only work if `com.android.browser` is killing itself, or if the killer is part of the system firmware and runs as the same user account as does `com.android.browser`.

Comment: +1 ohhkk my bad. "the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill"

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to your own use of `WebView`, just `finish()` your activity.

If you are referring to some other application, you cannot "close/terminate the browser programmatically", particularly if it is in the foreground.